# Undefined reference in C

Tags: c, struct, undefined-reference

I have include `unsigned short crc_message(unsigned int key, unsigned char *message, int num_bytes);` in my "data.h"

But when I try to use it in another code file

```
...
#include "data.h"
```

`unsigned short crc16 = crc_message(XMODEM_KEY, buff, nread);`

```
...
```

I always get

> In function `main':/h/u8/g3/00/g3helios/p33/g3helios/a2/packetize.c:57: undefined reference to`crc_message'collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Can someone tell me why? Thanks!

Comment: The header is one thing, but you need to link it to the implementation.

Comment: Is data.h in the same directory as your code and are you linking it when compiling?

Comment: Check out that data.h file is compiled and added into the library.

Comment: http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/12_Compiling_linking_Makefile_header_files.html is a good site to read about makefiles and linking

Comment: How are you compiling your program and where are the files located relatively?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to find crc_message() function in some library regarding crc and compile your program against it - for example if the library is called libcrc.so you have to do:

```
gcc -lcrc ...
```

Answer (score 0):

1.In header file `data.h` you have provided the prototype of function `crc_message`.

2.But, your problem is undefined reference error during linking stage.

3.So,did you define the function `crc_message` anywhere in your source ?

Comment: 3. I defined crc_message in another c file, which also includes "data.h".

Comment: 1.you can use nm command to check the symbols. nm can be used on lib,obj and exe file. 2.also check the link procedure in makefile once.